# Rails: Conditional Validation & Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, conditional-statements

What I'm thinking right now is...

I have a library full of books (entries). Each book has many checkouts (embedded document).

What I think I want to do is, upon checkout, make a new "checkout" as an embedded document. Upon checkin, I want to edit the checkout and add a "date_checked_out" field...

The issue is, my current model/controller makes a new entry each time there is a checkin or checkout...so it's doubly redundant...

What's the best way to go about this? Need more detail?

Checkout Controller:

```
  def new
    @entry = Entry.find(params[:entry_id])
    @checkout = @entry.checkout.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {render :layout => false}
    end
  end

  def create
    @entry = Entry.find(params[:entry_id])
    @entry.update_attributes(:checked_out => "Out")
    @checkout = @entry.checkout.create!(params[:checkout])
    redirect_to "/", :notice => "Book Checked Out!"
  end

class Checkout
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes

  field :checkout_date, :type => Time
  field :checkout_date_due, :type => Time
  field :book_in, :type => Time, :default => Time.now
  field :book_out, :type => Time, :default => Time.now

  embedded_in :entries, :inverse_of => :entries
end
```

Comment: Can you provide the model and controller code for the book and checkout?

Comment: @eabraham, see my update. Standard new/create methods and a typical model...nothing special yet.

Comment: Can you please post your Entry and Checkout models!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense the checkout would have a start and stop date.  Do you need to make a checkout when a checkin occurs?  You may be able to change this to an 'update' instead of a 'create' on the checkout controller - enter a checked_in_at on update.

Specifically - you'd want to be able to accept a PUT on the checkout controller - this could either be generic (allowing you to update the checkout in many ways) or specific, make a route that cleans up this for you:

```
resources :checkouts do
  put :checkin, :on => :member
end
```

in checkouts_controller

```
def checkin
  @checkout = Checkout.find(params[:id]
  @checkout.update_attribute(:checked_in_at, Time.now)

  # handle issues, redirect, etc.

end
```

Comment: the book needs a separate action for checkout/checkin. They should not happen at the same time. So, if a book is checked in, the link will say "checkout"--whereupon the user can checkout the book `status=>:checkedout` and enter a date. Then the link will change to `check in`...and at that point the user can check the book in at their leisure, but it should only UPDATE the previous checkout entry, not make a new one.

Comment: In other words...Starting from the checkedin condition--if checkout, set status to "Out" && create a new checkout. If it's "Out", don't create, update the previous entry.

Comment: I did just figure this out...I just put an if statement in my view and directed the form to the proper method, `update` or `create`. Simple. I think I was simultaneously confused and overcomplicating things.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it pure REST, add an update action to your Checkout controller.

Also, post your entry model. I'm assuming from your code that an entry has_one checkout, and a checkout belongs to an entry.

Something like:

***Edit because it appears OP wants to see how this works while checking for a conditional**

```
  ... original boilerplate code ommitted 
  def update
    @entry = Entry.find(params[:entry_id])
    # if the book is checked out
    if @entry.checked_out == "out"
      # then update it 
      @entry.update_attributes(:checked_out => "whatever" # though I'd seriously consider changing checked out to a boolean - if it's either out or in, true or false makes sense. Ignore this advice if there are more than two states
      @checkout = @entry.checkout
      respond_to do |format|
        if @checkout.update_attributes(:checked_out => "newValue")
        ...
        else
        .. handle errors
        end
      end
    else
      #the book does not have the correct status
      respond_to do |format|
         format.html { redirect_to some_action_path, :notice => "Entry is not out, so we cannot update its status." }
         format.json { render json: #entry.errors, status: :unprocessible_entry }
      end
    end
  end
```

Also, if you want to make the code a bit more explicit, you might consider taking swards advice and creating a few named endpoints like

```
def checkout

end

def checkin
end
```

I think that makes sense, in that someone else reading the code can very easily know exactly what that controller action is doing, as opposed to create and update.

Comment: This is right...but the crux of my question is how do I handle the conditional? I only need to update if the status of the book is "Out"...your code doesn't show me anything I can't quickly google. :/  ie. Is it better to have the condition in the controller or the view? (I'm assuming controller, as that's typical good practice). Also, how do I handle validations with these conditions?

Comment: I'm not positive what you're asking here, but you should have that conditional logic in both. On the controller end, the conditional ensures that even if a user intentionally or unintentionally bypasses your view(curl against your url, or reveals hidden js button), your application will still check before taking an action that might alter one of your models.